# Is swashbuckle.aspnetcore supporting asp.net core 3.0?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.0

I am installing a new asp.net core 3.0

its using    `services.AddControllers();` instead of `services.addMvc();`

and its using

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

instead of

```
app.UserMvc();
```

i tried adding `swashbuckle.aspnetcore` to generated its swagger ui.

its not working.

is `swashbuckle.aspnetcore` already supporting asp.net core 3.0 ?

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SwashBuckle.AspNetCore version 5.0.0-rc2 fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ASP.NET Core 3.0 supports Swashbuckle.

1) You can simply install it by running the follow command in Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore -Version 5.0.0-rc3
```

2) Then add the Swagger generator to the services collection in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

3) In `Startup.Configure` method, add these two to enable the middleware for serving the generated JSON document and the Swagger UI:

```
// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});
```

To customize it, you can check complete guide here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to access the swagger ui in 3.0 Preview 7 with the following:

```
<PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.0.4" />
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
...
   services.AddSwaggerDocument();
}

Configure() {
...
   app.UseSwaggerUi3();
}
```

Comment: ahh its not swashbuckle.aspnetcore, I believe its NSwag.